# How to change the Flutter AboutDialog Buttonlabels?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Im trying to use the AboutDialog but I want to change the button labels fitting to another language.

This is how the class gets the String value for the labeling:

```
TextButton(
 child: Text(MaterialLocalizations.of(context).closeButtonLabel),
  onPressed: () {
   Navigator.pop(context);
  },
),
```

I know I could just do a custom Dialog. But I wonder if it would be possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you want to change labels language?

Comment: I just want the button so say "close" in my language.